# Using JSON.Net to write a property name

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am using JSON.net to write some json in C#. I can produce JSON like this

```
{
    "id": "234",
    "name": "abc"
}
```

What i would like to do is get is this

```
 {
    "DATA": {
        "id": "234",
        "name": "abc"
    }
}
```

Here is the json.net code i'm using

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
    JsonWriter jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(sw);
    jsonWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;



        jsonWriter.WriteStartObject();                 
            jsonWriter.WritePropertyName("id");
            jsonWriter.WriteValue("234");
            jsonWriter.WritePropertyName("name");
            jsonWriter.WriteValue("abc");
        jsonWriter.WriteEndObject();
```

can you suggest how to add the 'DATA' section to it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Make the root object, then write the property name `"DATA"`, then write the object you just wrote:

```
jsonWriter.WriteStartObject();
    jsonWriter.WritePropertyName("DATA");
    jsonWriter.WriteStartObject();
        jsonWriter.WritePropertyName("id");
        jsonWriter.WriteValue("234");
        jsonWriter.WritePropertyName("name");
        jsonWriter.WriteValue("abc");
    jsonWriter.WriteEndObject();
jsonWriter.WriteEndObject();
```