# Adding the JsonWriter Namespace to my project

Tags: .net, json, wcf

I want to use the JsonWriter to create a representation of a custom object, the problem is that I can't find the namespace in which the JsonWriter Class resides, is it an external library or already embedded in the .netFramework? I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010, and the project is a Windows Communication Service using .net 4.0

Thanks in advance

Comment: "The" JsonWriter? A web search reveals several such classes - do you have any idea which one you mean?

Comment: I am trying to follow the example in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7327853/using-json-net-to-write-a-property-name

Comment: So the clue's in the title: Json.NET. Do a web search for that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could install the [JSON.NET NuGet](http://json.codeplex.com/):

```
Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
```

The `JsonWriter` class is defined in the `Newtonsoft.Json` assembly that will automatically be added to your project when you install the NuGet. Or you could also manually download and reference this assembly to your project.

Answer (score 1):

Given the post you've referred to, it looks like you're after [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com) ([NuGet package](http://nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json), [documentation](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/)).

Once you've got as far as installing that, you should be aware that you *don't* have to use `JsonWriter` directly - that's a relatively low level API. I've used Json.NET in a few projects, and never had to go that low - the ["LINQ to JSON" API](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/LINQtoJSON.htm) is a better fit in most cases, in my experience.

It's a bit like the XML APIs - you *can* use `XmlWriter` and `XmlReader`, but it's usually simpler to use a DOM representation such as LINQ to XML.

Also note that if you don't want an external dependency, you can use [`DataContractJsonSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx) which is built into .NET.